How do we reach an IP address?
How does the following work in TCP/IP protocol?
There are two subnets:

subnet A is 10.0.0.0/8
subnet B is 10.20.0.0/16

A host in Network A with an IP address of 10.20.3.4 wants to access a host 10.20.9.9 of network B.  (Eg an HTTP GET request to http://10.20.9.9).
How the default gateway of network A route the request?
How would it know the host under requested is within local network or another subnet if I don't explicitly indicate the subnet mask?

This is really broad - its worth looking up arp for a local network, and how routing works, outside the local network. Also DNS.

@JourneymanGeek  Can you revisit this - I think it was badly written (hopefully I've fixed that) - but it is quite answerable.

Hopefully this question gets re-opened and I can provide a full answer, but very briefly - 10.20.3.4 should be in network B, not network A.  If Subnet A and Subnet B are on different segments it will not work, as the request won't be routed to the gateway to forward to Subnet B.    If Subnet A and Subnet B are on the same segment, The host will broadcast to everything in the /8 and will get an ARP response back.  The traffic will go directly between the interfaces and will not go via the gateway.

I kinda started on an answer and was referring to multiple wikipedia answers. I'd knock out the bit about a URL, which is an entirely different problem and I think it'll end up usable

So - default gateway of Network A will not receive the request.   You can check if the hosts are in the same subnet.  If they are they will communicate directly.   You can double-check this by doing a traceroute and seeing if there is an intermediate hop or not.  If they are in the same segment there will be no intermediate hop.   You would not put a subnet mask in a browser URL as it makes no sense.  A browser establishes a TCP connection - it has no knowledge of the routing table, so cant make use of the netmask.

How does the following work in TCP/IP protocol? It doesn't. Subnets should never overlap.

The book Wendell Odom Networking First Step, is excellent and explains this. He wrote the Cisco cerification material too.

Wrong subnetting was done here, network B is a 'PART' of network A


How the default gateway of network A route the request?

The first problem / question would actually be: how would the 10.20.3.4 host route / handle the request?
Normally when you configure an IP address on a host with a prefix length less than 32, a direct route for the IP subnet indicated by the prefix length (and the address) would also be configured.
In the case of Ethernet, when the route used for a destination is a direct route, no gateway would be involved (because in a direct route, by definition there's no gateway address). Therefore, instead of resolving a gateway (IP) address into a destination MAC address, the destination IP address is what would get resolved.
In other words, assuming the destination IP get resolved successfully, in that case the traffics (encapsulated in Ethernet frames) would be L2 forwarded by a respective switch from the source host to the destination host directly (since the L2 destination address and the L3 one refers to the same host). No L3 forwarding would occur since no router is involved. (Note that your home router is essentially a router with a switch attached to its LAN interface.)
If no ARP response is received for the resolution attempt, the host will not try another route either (if any).
Assuming you have/add a route for 10.0.0.0/8 on either the source host or the router between the two networks, only traffics with destination that is within 10.0.0.0/8 but is not within 10.20.0.0/16 would use the route, because the route with the longest prefix length is essentially always preferred (unless when for example there is more than one route table and routing policies).
Since the router is attached to both networks, it means that it would have (direct) route for both subnets. Even if you try to use the router forcefully on the source host (10.20.3.4) by adding a indirect route, the router would try to resolve (10.20.9.9) through ARP request (sent out of the interface of the corresponding route, i.e., the one that is attached with the link that connects to the network that 10.20.3.4 is in) when it receive the packets. Obviously it means that it would either end up forwarding the packet to a "wrong" 10.20.9.9, or will not forward it out at all.
One way to "workaround" is to add a route of even longer prefix length. For example, if 10.20.9.9 is the only / one of a few hosts in the "remote" network that you need to access, and you don't mind the accessibility to the 10.20.9.9 in the "local" network, if any, is "suppressed", you can add a "host route" (prefix length of 32) for 10.20.9.9 on both the source host and the router. On the router it would be a direct route, in which you need to set the correct interface as per your desire. (In at least some system, you can add a "bogus" indirect route by using the IP address configured on the correct interface as the gateway address. Such indirect route would likely work as if it is a direct route.)
It might be worth mentioning that default route means that the destination block covered is 0.0.0.0/0. Since its prefix length is 0, it would be used only if the destination address is not covered by any other "non-default" route in your route table.

The question could be stated as “ when we open browser and type an ip address (for domain name it will be eventually translated to an IP) then how my network gateway can determine the network address from this IP addr then route it to the dest?”

@WallaceZ: I think you need to rewrite the question using a better example, then – one that actually reflects a standard configuration.

@WallaceZ routes in its route table, if the gateway is even involved
